# Format-Table outputting each object into separate table

Tags: powershell

My function queries a `CimInstance` for one or more computers, and stores the uptime info in an object (`$obj`). If `$obj` contains less than 5 properties, everything displays fine as a single table. When I have 5 properties, it defaults to a list, and if I pipe that to `Format-Table`, it outputs a separate table for each computer. Is there a reason for this? Is there something I can do to display all five properties and have one contiguous table?

```
function Get-LKUptime {
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true,
             ValueFromPipeline = $True,
             ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $True)]
        [string[]]$computername=$env:COMPUTERNAME
    )

    foreach ($computer in $computername) {
        if (Test-Connection $computer -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
            try {
                $os = Get-CimInstance -ErrorAction 'Stop' -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $computer
                $status = 'OK'
                $continue = $true
            } catch {
                Write-Warning "Unable to query WMI info for $computer"
                $status = 'ERROR'
            }

            if ($continue) {
                $uptime = ((New-Timespan -Start $os.LastBootUpTime -End $os.LocalDateTime).TotalDays -as [int])
                if ($uptime -gt 30) {
                    $patch = $true
                } else {
                    $patch = $false
                }
            }
        } else {
            Write-Warning "Connection to $computer failed. $computer may be offline"
            $status = 'OFFLINE'
        }

        $properties = [Ordered]@{
            'ComputerName' = $computer;
            'StartTime' = $os.LastBootUpTime;
            'Uptime (Days)' = $uptime;
            'Status' = $status;
            'MightNeedPatched' = $patch
        }

        $obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $properties
        $obj | Format-Table
    }
}
```

4 properties:

[image: output for objects with 4 properties]

5 properties:

[image: output for objects with 5 properties]

Comment: You invoke separate instance of `Format-Table` for each object, thus you have separate table. IMHO, does not use `Format-*` in functions, because it makes impossible to process output of your function. Instead, allow consumer to specify desired format: `Get-LKUptime|ft`. If you really want just to change default formatting, then assign custom type name for your objects, and define custom format for that type name in `Format.ps1xml` file.

Comment: And, BTW, your function declared as accepting pipeline input, but you does not have `process` block to process it, so your implicit `end` block will process only last pipeline input.

Comment: @PetSerAl - I looked at this also - However when I only store four properties into $obj - the same code outputs as a single table the way I want it to. It only does this after I add a 5th property. Thanks for the info about process block

Comment: Are you sure, that you are talking about same code with explicit call to `Format-Table`? I just remove `'MightNeedPatched' = $patch` line from your function and [that](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LnqBl.png) is what I get.

Comment: Sorry - I have just noticed the error I posted. Sorry for the confusion
If I do not explicitly call Format-Table in my code AND IF $obj has only 4 properties. It displays as one table.

If I add a 5th property I.e. mightneedpatched - The default output is list
If I pipe that to format-table OR let the user pipe to format-table I get two tables. One for each computer

Comment: If I remove `| format-table` from your function and add it after function call, then I got [one table](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4y4lr.png).

Comment: What @PetSerAl said. Don't do output formatting in a function for fetching data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `Format-*` cmdlets in function, because it replace original objects with formatting objects which are unusable for further processing. Instead you should define custom formatting for you type.

**LiamKemp.Format.ps1xml:**

```
<Configuration>
  <ViewDefinitions>
    <View>
      <Name>LiamKemp.UptimeInfo</Name>
      <ViewSelectedBy>
        <TypeName>LiamKemp.UptimeInfo</TypeName>
      </ViewSelectedBy>
      <TableControl>
        <TableRowEntries>
          <TableRowEntry>
            <TableColumnItems>
              <TableColumnItem>
                <PropertyName>ComputerName</PropertyName>
              </TableColumnItem>
              <TableColumnItem>
                <PropertyName>StartTime</PropertyName>
              </TableColumnItem>
              <TableColumnItem>
                <PropertyName>Uptime (Days)</PropertyName>
              </TableColumnItem>
              <TableColumnItem>
                <PropertyName>Status</PropertyName>
              </TableColumnItem>
              <TableColumnItem>
                <PropertyName>MightNeedPatched</PropertyName>
              </TableColumnItem>
            </TableColumnItems>
          </TableRowEntry>
        </TableRowEntries>
      </TableControl>
    </View>
  </ViewDefinitions>
</Configuration>
```

Then you can load your format file:

```
Update-FormatData .\LiamKemp.Format.ps1xml
```

Or if you pack your function in module, then you should use `FormatsToProcess` key.

And you modify your function to add custom type name to output objects:

```
function Get-LKUptime {
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true,
             ValueFromPipeline = $True,
             ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $True)]
        [string[]]$computername=$env:COMPUTERNAME
    )

    process {
        foreach ($computer in $computername) {
            if (Test-Connection $computer -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
                try {
                    $os = Get-CimInstance -ErrorAction 'Stop' -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $computer
                    $status = 'OK'
                    $continue = $true
                } catch {
                    Write-Warning "Unable to query WMI info for $computer"
                    $status = 'ERROR'
                }

                if ($continue) {
                    $uptime = ((New-Timespan -Start $os.LastBootUpTime -End $os.LocalDateTime).TotalDays -as [int])
                    if ($uptime -gt 30) {
                        $patch = $true
                    } else {
                        $patch = $false
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Write-Warning "Connection to $computer failed. $computer may be offline"
                $status = 'OFFLINE'
            }

            [PSCustomObject]@{
                'ComputerName' = $computer;
                'StartTime' = $os.LastBootUpTime;
                'Uptime (Days)' = $uptime;
                'Status' = $status;
                'MightNeedPatched' = $patch
            } | Add-Member -TypeName LiamKemp.UptimeInfo -PassThru

        }
    }
}
```

And now output of your function formatted as table by default.